# Wordpress security regarding plugins and coding with snippet plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, security, plugins

I have just started learning PHP, loving it, and advancing pretty quickly. I am using Code Snippets plugin because of its simplicity, and when getting into configuring API calls and storing into the database (key point being I'm using credentials in the code) I stopped and thought ''wait is this secure?"

So I did as much research as I could with my limited knowledge of the pertinent terminology to find out that the code I am writing is actually stored in the database.

Furthermore, my understanding is that Wordpress credentials are all stored and encrypted in the database and that there is a secure process of storing in the database. But if all data is encrypted by default or if only encrypted when configured to do so, I have no idea.

A brief summary of my current situation would be:

- I am not well educated with higher/lower security risks of having information contained in the database vs folders (this is my main problem and main focus of my question)
- Appart from checking the author of a plugin, I am unable to forge a educated opinion on ''if it is secure"
- Appart from having a web server configured correctly by my hosting provider, I do not understand at which point PHP code or other elements that should not be accessed can become accessible.
- I am using Wordfence plugin (WAF disabled), Cloudflare WAF and Cloudflare CDN (mentioning in case it could matter)

In the end, I would immensely appreciate some enlightening into going in the right direction moving forward in coding PHP and raising security flags when coding/installing plugins.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I understand how child themes can work in a convenient way, but I am, of course, not able to understand why it would be a more secure way to do things or not.

Comment: I'm really not clear on what you actual question is, however I'd recommend looking into [PHP: The Right Way](https://phptherightway.com/) which is an opiniated but generally well-respected site that includes a section on security. Nothing in WordPress is encrypted (by default), instead passwords are hashed, you'll want to look into the difference between those. I would encourage you to learn FTP/SFTP/SSH/etc. to write files instead of snippets into a plugin.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I guess the question was "could you please enlighten me on these concerns and/or point me in the right direction to educate myself?". Your answer is most helpful. I'm realizing how little control/overview I have  with a snippets plugin and that FTP is definitely the way to go. I will most certainly put PHP: The Right Way to good use as well. Thank you.